# Android WebRTC compile

Tags: android, git, webrtc, gclient

for a project i need the WebRTC for Android. Now i am trying to compile
the WebRTC-Sources to get the latest version. I am following the instructions for depot_tools:
[depot_tools_tutorial(7) Manual Page](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up)

```
$ git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git > all_operations_log.txt 2>&1
$ export PATH=/media/siegfried/c2c87048-79c5-45a2-a71c-111fae6b5bc1/siegfried/webrtc_android/depot_tools:$PATH
$ echo $PATH >> all_operations_log.txt 2>&1
$ fetch --nohooks webrtc_android >> all_operations_log.txt 2>&1
$ gclient sync >> all_operations_log.txt 2>&1
```

Now i get the following errors:

```
[0:34:39] Resolving deltas: 100% (480763/480763)
[0:34:43] error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance too far back)
[0:34:43] error: Could not read c2df76e49944bd7e58e686e4d1d2f28338b7deb9
[0:34:43] fatal: revision walk setup failed
[0:34:43] error: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/tools did not send all necessary objects
[0:34:49] error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance too far back)
[0:34:49] error: Could not read c2df76e49944bd7e58e686e4d1d2f28338b7deb9
[0:34:49] fatal: revision walk setup failed
[0:34:49] error: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/tools did not send all necessary objects
----------------------------------------
Error: Command 'git -c core.deltaBaseCacheLimit=2g fetch origin --no-tags' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /media/siegfried/c2c87048-79c5-45a2-a71c-111fae6b5bc1/siegfried/webrtc_android/src/tools


Warnings:
Conflicting directory /media/siegfried/c2c87048-79c5-45a2-a71c-111fae6b5bc1/siegfried/webrtc_android/src/tools moved to /media/siegfried/c2c87048-79c5-45a2-a71c-111fae6b5bc1/siegfried/webrtc_android/_bad_scm/src/toolsw2duv9_2.
Conflicting directory /media/siegfried/c2c87048-79c5-45a2-a71c-111fae6b5bc1/siegfried/webrtc_android/src/third_party moved to /media/siegfried/c2c87048-79c5-45a2-a71c-111fae6b5bc1/siegfried/webrtc_android/_bad_scm/src/third_partyfw8bvd2e.
Running: gclient root
Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "name": "src",
    "url": "https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src.git",
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "managed": False,
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
target_os = ["android", "unix"]
'
Running: gclient sync --nohooks --with_branch_heads
Subprocess failed with return code 1.
depot_tools update failed. Couldn't fetch main branch.
Retry later or reclone depot_tools
error: Hash stimmt nicht mit 4a9d989f52e9be9f50b3af38d02b51e63350bd05 überein.
error: Object 83b45179e639666e8d8e72e9b73f4b71614da170 not a commit
error: Object 757f20796948ff4a9264dad5293bdff2f94d9c43 not a commit
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect header check)
error: Could not read a2862ded8ef8d96fa612e0a37aef77906db35c1a
fatal: SHA1 KOLLISION MIT 4a9d989f52e9be9f50b3af38d02b51e63350bd05 GEFUNDEN !
fatal: fetch-pack: ungültige index-pack Ausgabe
```

I have tried also to use another branch as main, but here are the same result.

I would appreciate any hints to solve the problem.

Best regards,

sikienzl